# Ubuntu 10.04: Bash script fails in cronjob when [-e ] test is used

Tags: bash, testing, ubuntu, cron

I'm running a script fine from the command line, but it fails when put into a cronjob. I've narrowed it down to specifically a problem with testing for file existence with [ -e "name" ].  With this running in Ubuntu 32-bit desktop, I can write the following script and have it work when called from the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define statements
IMPORT="/home/${USER}/data_imports/fitb"
ARCHIVE="${IMPORT}/archive"
declare -a CENTERS
CENTERS[0]="ct"
CENTERS[1]="ny"
len=${#CENTERS[*]}
RUNDATE=`date --date=yesterday +"%m%d"`
ARCHIVEDATE=`date --date=yesterday +"%Y_%m_%d"`

i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
  if [ -e "${ARCHIVE}/fitb_${ARCHIVEDATE}_${CENTERS[i]}.csv" ]
  then touch ~/data_imports/fitb/shell_${i}.rn
  fi
  let i++
done
```

If I comment out the lines "if", "then", & "fi" after putting the touch command on its own line, the while loop runs fine in a cronjob.  If I put the if test back in, I get nothing. To test if it's even being picked up by the cron daemon, I moved the touch command to the line after the shebang, so it's the first command that runs.  This fails to produce anything.  I know the files tested for with -e are in the proper location, with global rx permission.  Could it be that -e needs to be +w for the test to succeed?I thought it could be due to the fact that variables aren't inhereted by subshells (of which, to my understanding, the tst is a sort), but if that were the case, I would think the CLI invocation would fail as well.

Comment: 9 times out of 10, if a cronjob doesn't work (but script works in an interactive session), there's an issue with some environment variables.

Comment: Try to echo the file you are testing into /tmp/blah or something and run that from cron to see if that's the file that you expect. If it's not, the it's probably environment variables just as asf107 suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be relying on ${USER} being defined. That's not the case when running as a cronjob.

Comment: I thought about that after reading a bit about bash testing, but I tested by having it touch ${IMPORT}/shell_${i}.rn.  I don't know what I messed up in testing it, but that seems to have been the issue. It's possible I had put 
    USER=`whoami` 
in, as the cron job now runs fine. Thank you.